# Set input [type=range] max value based on another input[type=text] value in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Please give me correct code for..

First input enter value is equals to input[type=range] value in angular

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="{{income.value}}" value="{{income.min}}" ng-model="income.value">

<input type="range" min="0" max="" value="{{income.min}}" ng-model="income.value">
```

Below is the Controller code:

```
$scope.income = {
    min: 0,
    max: '',
    value:0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ngModel` to control the values and define `min` and `max` with the `income` values as in the example bellow.

```
<input type="range" ng-model="income.value" max="{{ income.max }}" min="{{ income.min }}">
<input type="text" ng-model="income.max">
<input type="text" ng-model="income.min">
```

The following snippet implements this solution using `income` values.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.income = { min: 0, max: 100, value:0 }

  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  
  <input type="range" 
         ng-model="income.value"
         max="{{ income.max }}"
         min="{{ income.min }}">
  {{ income.value }}<br>  
  max <input type="text" ng-model="income.max"><br>  
  min <input type="text" ng-model="income.min"><br>  
  <pre>{{ income | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Lenilson de Castro